# Exporting products, Import/Export profiles - Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getConfigurableAttributes()

Tags: magento-1.8, importexport, fatal-error, cvs

I am trying to export all products using Magento's Import/Export profiles. However it is giving me this error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method**

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getConfigurableAttributes() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mywebsite.local/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php on line 77
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `getConfigurableAttributes()` is function of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable` that means it works when product  type is configurable and totally does not work for simple products.

On class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price` at line no 77 the error shows up. This code is called when `getTotalConfigurableItemsPrice()` function is called. You called this function for simple products, that's why it shows an error.